# how to use twitter API with android

Tags: android, twitter

i have search at lot on google but could not found a perfect answer to my question.Not even here.
I followed [this](http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2011/02/13/guide-to-integrating-twitter-android-application/) but still its giving me an error.

and i m unable to get whats the problem 
help plz.

LogCAt :

```
03-11 13:13:38.609: E/AndroidRuntime(795): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
03-11 13:13:38.609: E/AndroidRuntime(795): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
03-11 13:13:38.609: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
03-11 13:13:38.609: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
03-11 13:13:38.609: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
03-11 13:13:38.609: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
03-11 13:13:38.609: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
03-11 13:13:38.609: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
03-11 13:13:38.609: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
03-11 13:13:38.609: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-11 13:13:38.609: E/AndroidRuntime(795): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: twitter4j.auth.AccessToken
03-11 13:13:38.609: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at com.ecs.sample.TwitterUtils.getHomeTimeline(TwitterUtils.java:33)
03-11 13:13:38.609: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at com.ecs.sample.AndroidTwitterGoogleApiJavaClientActivity$ApiCallExecutor.doInBackground(AndroidTwitterGoogleApiJavaClientActivity.java:78)
03-11 13:13:38.609: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at com.ecs.sample.AndroidTwitterGoogleApiJavaClientActivity$ApiCallExecutor.doInBackground(AndroidTwitterGoogleApiJavaClientActivity.java:1)
03-11 13:13:38.609: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-11 13:13:38.609: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
03-11 13:13:38.609: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  ... 4 more
```

Build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

Comment: downvoter please comment for downvotes or answer if you can!!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you have not included this in your application somewhere. `NoClassDefFoundError: twitter4j.auth.AccessToken`

Comment: Did you add it to your build.gradle file?

Comment: Update your post, add the build.gradle file contents so we can see what you have.

Comment: Where is the twitter4j library? Is it in the `libs` directory?

Comment: yeah i have added that using buildpath. twitter4j-core4.0.2 jar

Comment: please help i m stuked.i hope you will.

Comment: If you're including the jar file in the libs directory and that is your app. Did you try refreshing the gradle dependencies Tools > Android > Sync Project with Gradle Files

Comment: can you help me on skype : stacktrace8

Answer (score 0):

Twitter has launched its own SDK. You can use that for better access to the twitter APIs. 
https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/integrate

Comment: do you have any example ?? it will help me .

Comment: Sry I tried using it once but the twitter sdk provider 'Fabric'  didn't authenticate me for 2 consecutive days. After that I didn't got time to work on it. But the whole implementation idea is clearly given on the link which I shared above.